# Full width video background

Tags: css, html, video

I'm attempting my first web video project and am getting nowhere and need a little help with using a full width video header or background.

I found an example that does what I am trying to do using the below videos and it works just fine - no buffering, acceptable quality, etc.

The .mp4 file uses a 640x360 format @ 23 fps (613kbps) and this works fine on any display I view it - the whole frame is visible top to bottom, side to side.

The research I've done indicates the best video format to use is 720 x 24fps, which I have tried (actual dimension is 1280x720) but found it only works well on less than maximized browser resolutions, in which case, it looks great, otherwise, a small portion of the bottom, maybe the bottom 18% of the frame, is not visible until you scroll down, which is unacceptable.  I need the video to work as well as the 640x360 with the whole image visible. In addition, buffering occurs with the 720 format, whereas there is no buffering with the 640x360.

I am using Sony Vegas for the video editing and there is no option for a 640x360 format.  The closest is 640x480 but that produces the same result - to tall and the bottom is not visible.

There is a site that uses the 1280x720 format successfully (http://mazwai.com/#/) but I have no idea how.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank You.

This is  the current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Video test</title>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".player").mb_YTPlayer();
});
</script>

<style>
body{ margin:0px; background:#000; max-width:1000; }
#bg_container{ height:800px; overflow:auto; }
#bg{ width:100%; }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="bg_container">
  <video id="bg" src="www.parishpc.com/images/720.mp4" autoplay loop muted">    </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code worked a little bit better - only the bottom 5% was not visible:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Video test</title>

<style>

body, html { margin: auto;
background:#fff;
height: 100%;
}

header {
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

.video {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    z-index:1;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <video autoplay loop class="video">
            <source src="www.parishpc.com/images/720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </header>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you cannot rely on consistent screen resolutions, you could do `#bg_container{margin:0 auto;}` and use JavaScript to determine the screen height, then determine what the width should be, keeping in mind `#bg_contaier` and your video should be the same height and width.

Comment: I added 'height:800px;" in #bg_container simply out of desperation. I tried 100% and auto and  got the same results.

Comment: Use JavaScript `innerHeight` to get the widow height. You don't actually have to put `window.` before it, as `window` is implicit. Oh, you're using jQuery... `$('#bg, #bg_container').height($(window).height())`.

Comment: 1280x720 and 640x360 fit nicely because they are both 16:9 aspect ratio which is standard. 640x480 is 16:12 AR to which I don't rightly recall if there's such a standard.

Comment: @Texson BTW I noticed that you have invoked mbYTPlayer plugin....why don't you just use that? It's purpose is to cover your background with a video edge to edge. Not only that, if you are using that plugin, then you are using YouTube and if you are using YouTube, the video get's sized to 16:9 AR by default.

Comment: ok.  have it working reasonably well using the 2nd code listing above.  I did, after much looking, find ONE format in Sony Vegas to render the video to  640x360, although I had to adjust the frame rate from 29 to 24 fps and got the desired results - no buffering, acceptable quality, fast loading and FULL WIDTH.  A small portion of the images used did get cut off at the bottom so the text had to be raised a bit, but it still looks ok.  Would really like to resolve the matter so that I do get 100% of the image in.

Comment: This feels more like smoke and mirrors having to make it work this way, so I appreciate everyone's input and suggestions.  I will update this thread as I make progress regarding the problem.

Comment: The working version can be seen at www.parishpc.com.

Comment: Oddly enough, there is a plethora of 'how to's' regarding doing this, but every article falls short on the graphic nuts and bolts, rather, they just expand on the code portion.

Comment: Thanks for that info, zer00ne.  I will try it and will let you know. As you can see, I omitted it from the second code listing because it simply wasn't doing what I wanted, but admit, that might be my fault in the code, which is why I came here for help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still trying to make the video take up the entire viewport, this can be done with the following code ->
(I am also fairly certain this requires you to add the video through your .html using the  tag, instead of adding it as a background in your css properties)

Set your parent container you want to fill the video with to:

```
position: relative;
```

Add the following properties to your video:

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: -2;
object-fit: fill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding:0;
}
```

and remove `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` from video class

This should work

Let me know if you require any further help

Comment: I tried the changes but they did not solve the problem.  Sorry, and thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Once also try after removing margin :auto from body, html and height: 100% from header

Comment: Fantastic article.  Thanks so much for that link.  He is right, it is such a cool and useful effect.  I will try it with the video and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Glad if it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but having a video background without stretching or cut off parts is impossible to do while accommodating to every user's window size.

This solution will make sure the video is 100% of the window's height. If they want to see the cut off parts they'd have to resize their window to fit the width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Video test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100%;
            width: auto;
        }

        .video {
            height: 100%;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <video autoplay loop class="video">
            <source src="http://www.parishpc.com/images/720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, if you visit the sight (www.parishpc.com), you will see what is close to the effect I am trying to achieve.  But, I will agree with you in as much as it is 'almost' impossible to achieve given the infinite resolutions.  I disagree in the sense that you can probably write the code to accomplish this, but it will be complex and involved.  I'm trying to find a happy in-between.  I have images I want to fit the viewport size and know that the whole image appeared and did not cut off important text at the bottom.

Comment: I have spent the day experimenting, researching, copying code, writing code, modifying code...you name it.  The problem is that it IS video.  If it was just content, it could be satisfactorily and dynamically rearranged to still look good with out losing important content.  And that would be the case here if I did not need an exact fit.  The whole thing is literally hurting my head.  I have had a bad headache all day tackling this.  So I really, REALLY appreciate yours and everyone's input, suggestions and help.  You guys are great.